# Regarding storing complex datas, and retrieving complex datas using node.js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to store a task into mongodb such as simple adding like 1+1, or a list of questions, but so far I only got to store simple data such as a string, I have some idea regarding how database work conceptually, but is new to actually implementing a database operation, so if anyone can give me some hints regarding to this issue it would be much appreciated.

```
var Task = new Schema({
  task: String
});

var Task = mongoose.model('Task', Task);

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();


app.put('/tasks/:id', function(req, res){
  Task.findById(req.params.id, function (err, doc){
    doc.updated_at = new Date();
    doc.task = req.body.task.task;
    doc.save(function(err) {
      if (!err){
        res.redirect('/tasks');
      }
      else {
        // error handling
     }
   });
  });
```

Comment: Are you trying to store questions into your task. Give me an idea of what you intend to store in task.

Comment: Seems like what you're asking is very broad and requires a whole tutorial. Take a lot @ [this](http://madhums.me/2012/07/19/breaking-down-app-js-file-nodejs-express-mongoose/)

Comment: I want to store two types of task, 1. simple arithmetic 2. list of questions, right now I am just trying to get the second type to work, I am attemping to store a list of questions that can be randomly chosen to present to the user, each question may or may not have a definite answer

Comment: currently I am only capable of storing one question at a time for each task, and that is also without corresponding answer, so what I did is I iterate through all the task to generate a single survey, but I think there is a better way of doing this, though I am new to node.js and hence the question

Comment: `task: [{ type: String }]`, enables you to store a list of questions as an Array.

Comment: What you really need is a separate schema for `Questions`. That'll be the ideal way to go about it

Comment: if I have multiple data in TASK, how would I retrieve it from the database

Comment: No, that's not possible. Would you like to move this to chat instead, so I can talk you thru it?

Comment: yes, that would be great

Comment: Seems like you can't chat, you don't have enough reputations

Comment: ok, seems like the site that you provide has some good example, I am going try to understand it, thanks for the help, really appreciated